# ant build android project tools/ant/build.xml:785 null returned: 139

Tags: android, ant, build

I use ant update an android project to target android-8 then use ant to build the project,but I got the error:
BUILD FAILED
/home/fengzhiping/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:769: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/fengzhiping/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:785: null returned: 139

Why ant build failure?Anyone can help me? 
I use ubuntu11.04 and the android tools version is Android SDK Tools Revision 15.